# Is there a common name for an object whose image is either 1 or -1?

Tags: terminology

Is there a common way to express the idea of "$\pm 1$" using words, ideally without spelling out "plus or minus one". Not that the absolute value is one, but that the value is either 1 or -1.

For example, without using the symbols "$\pm 1$", how would one say "If $Q \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is orthogonal, then $\det(Q) = \pm 1$"?

Comment: This is very weird. What's wrong with "plus or minus"?! Why would *another* group of words, whose meaning has to be explained, be a good idea when you have "plus or minus one", whose meaning is transparent? Math is already quite hard for a lot of people: finding ways to obscure it more is not exactly a great idea!

Comment: «The determinant of Q is plus or minus one.»

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez. I am looking for multiple succinct ways of conveying math ideas without using symbols.

Comment: Maybe "...of unit size."

Comment: @sean-roberson That might work, but I would like to distinguish in the complex case from a value on the unit circle to simply $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

What about $|\det(Q)| = 1$? Isn't it equivalent to $\det(Q) = \pm 1$ ?
Or would you prefer "$\det(Q)$ of square $1$"?

Comment: I like the "of square one" idea since it works in the reals, but this allows for multiple possibilities in complex values. It's a little like saying "of norm one".

Comment: Right. But for integer matrices, there is a proper name as you wish: *unimodular*. Unfortunately, I don't think it is used for complex matrices.

Comment: This could be what I'm looking for. Do you know the etymology of  _unimodular_ ? I found [this link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unimodular) to it on Wiktionary defining it as "of a lattice or matrix having a determinant of 1 or -1".  Would you call it an abuse of terminology to talk about either orthogonal matrices or their determinant having _the unimodular property_?